# D3-based graph, laggy zoom on Android

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, graph, svelte

I have successfully implemented pan & zoom on my d3-based graph, it runs butterly smooth on desktop, but pinch-to-zoom on mobile (only Android, iOS is just as smooth as on Desktop) is way too laggy. Panning runs just fine though.

This is the custom zoom handler I am using right now

```
let zoom_handler = d3.zoom().on("zoom", (e) => {
  g.attr("transform", e.transform);
  g.style("stroke-width", 3 / Math.sqrt(e.transform.k));
});
```

and then I call it on my svg parent like this:

```
svg.call(zoom_handler);
```

Just for context, *svg* and *g* variables are so defined:

```
const svg = d3
  .create("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
  .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

const g = svg.append("g");
```

Also, at this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFLU7.jpg) you can find a short video of the behavior (on Desktop).

I have tried it on a Redmi Note 7, 8 (Chrome latest version, both bad) and iPhone 7 (Safari, butter smooth).

I am suspecting that this does not involve D3 at all, that it might be just OS-related, but I hope I am wrong.

Comment: Can you make a quick REPL ?